# App freezing after I reorder using LongPressGesture

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add the LongPressGesture method of reordering tableview cells. But when I run the app in simulator, it freezes after I press on a cell to reorder, and I can't figure out what is causing it.

Here's are the relevant parts of my ViewController

import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var stories = [URL]()

var storyEnglishTitles:[String:String] = [
    "A":"AEnglish",
    "B":"BEnglish",
    "C":"CEnglish",
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Stories, translated"

    stories = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "txt", subdirectory: nil)!

    let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("longPressGestureRecognized:")))
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)
}

func longPressGestureRecognized(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let longpress = gestureRecognizer as! UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    let state = longpress.state
    let locationInView = longpress.location(in: self.tableView)
    var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: locationInView)

    switch state {
    case .began:
        if indexPath != nil {
            Path.initialIndexPath = indexPath
            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! UITableViewCell
            My.cellSnapShot = snapshopOfCell(inputView: cell)
            var center = cell.center
            My.cellSnapShot?.center = center
            My.cellSnapShot?.alpha = 0.0
            self.tableView.addSubview(My.cellSnapShot!)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                center.y = locationInView.y
                My.cellSnapShot?.center = center
                My.cellSnapShot?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05)
                My.cellSnapShot?.alpha = 0.98
                cell.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                if finished {
                    cell.isHidden = true
                }
            })
        }

    case .changed:
        var center = My.cellSnapShot?.center
        center?.y = locationInView.y
        My.cellSnapShot?.center = center!
        if ((indexPath != nil) && (indexPath != Path.initialIndexPath)) {

            self.stories.swapAt((indexPath?.row)!, (Path.initialIndexPath?.row)!)
            self.tableView.moveRow(at: Path.initialIndexPath!, to: indexPath!)
            Path.initialIndexPath = indexPath
        }

    default:
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: Path.initialIndexPath!) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.isHidden = false
        cell.alpha = 0.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            My.cellSnapShot?.center = cell.center
            My.cellSnapShot?.transform = .identity
            My.cellSnapShot?.alpha = 0.0
            cell.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            if finished {
                Path.initialIndexPath = nil
                My.cellSnapShot?.removeFromSuperview()
                My.cellSnapShot = nil
            }
        })
    }
}

func snapshopOfCell(inputView: UIView) -> UIView {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inputView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    inputView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    let cellSnapshot : UIView = UIImageView(image: image)
    cellSnapshot.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cellSnapshot.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
    cellSnapshot.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -5.0, height: 0.0)
    cellSnapshot.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    cellSnapshot.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
    return cellSnapshot
}

struct My {
    static var cellSnapShot: UIView? = nil
}

struct Path {
    static var initialIndexPath: IndexPath? = nil
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stories.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoryCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let storyForeignTitle = stories[indexPath.row].deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
    cell.textLabel?.text = storyForeignTitle
    let subtitleEnglishTitles = storyEnglishTitles[hymnGurmukhiTitle]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = subtitleEnglishTitles
    return cell 

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
        vc.selectedStory = stories[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Here is the error message from my console:

2018-05-04 15:40:54.047849-0700 Folkstory[1891:628678] -[Folkstory.ViewController longPressGestureRecognized:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10390c190
2018-05-04 15:40:54.048686-0700 Folkstory[1891:628678] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Folkstory.ViewController longPressGestureRecognized:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10390c190'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x181d82d8c 0x180f3c5ec 0x181d90098 0x18be36de4 0x181d885c8 0x181c6e41c 0x18bb32750 0x18c09f2a4 0x18bc94e6c 0x18bb317a8 0x18c090ac4 0x181d2a910 0x181d28238 0x181d28884 0x181c48da8 0x183c2b020 0x18bc2978c 0x102accc54 0x1816d9fc0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Updated this line:

let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(action: #selector(self.longPressGestureRecognized(_:)))

Now getting the error: Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'longPressGestureRecognized' .... which is odd because the next code is func longPressGestureRecognized(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer).

I also get two other maybe related conditional errors. Both of these lines in the func longPressGestureRecognized method give the same error. These lines:

```
let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: Path.initialIndexPath!) as! UITableViewCell
```

Give the error: Forced cast from 'UITableViewCell?' to 'UITableViewCell' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Solution: This is a Swift 3 to Swift 4 issue and I want to add what fixed it for me in case someone else out there is looking for the answer.

First add @objc to the method:

```
@objc func longPressGestureRecognized(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {}
```

Second update this line:

```
let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("longPressGestureRecognized:")))
```

to the following to make it Swift 4 compatible:

```
let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.longPressGestureRecognized))
```

Comment: Does it give you any error messages?

Comment: I'm still a noob when it comes to error messages. I set up breakpoints in effort to diagnose thise. I'm getting "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1" in AppDelegate at -  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: Yea I’ve been there. I’m talking about a message that appears in your console.

Comment: I just added the 2 errors I'm getting in my console to the post above. Some issue with my longpressed selector?

Comment: Change your selector syntax to `#selector(self.longPressGestureRecognized(_:))`

Comment: Thank you. Now getting a different error on the same line. Updated the main post.

Comment: Try adding `@objc` before `func longPressGestureRecognized`

Comment: Still same error

Comment: Add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your class declaration... if that doesn’t work I’ll need to take a deeper look at what’s going on.

Comment: Hey Jake. I think I've figured it out. Seemed to be a swift 3 to 4 issue and I've added it to my post above. Thank you for almost getting there with the obj C. That in addition to one other part solved my problem!